# drop [jenkins-2] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

When Jenkins 2.x was introduced in 2016, it was substantially different to Jenkins 1 (https://jenkins.io/2.0/), so I guess a `[jenkins-2]`was created to disambiguate. The tag never really caught on as there are only 118 tagged with it.

There are almost 39000 tagged `[jenkins]` and another 18 `[jenkins*]` tags to boot. Jenkins 1 is now deprecated, obsolete and unsupported. Almost all new `[jenkins]`questions are in fact Jenkins 2 related now (or jenkins-pipeline).

Only about 20 questions have `[jenkins-2]  -[jenkins]`, 8 unanswered, probably as not a watched tag.

Propose dropping the `[jenkins-2]` tag altogether and adding the jenkins tag to those missing. Can this be done in bulk?

Other meta Q complained about bulk edits, so best to ask first?

ps: only noticed this after a search for `[jenkins] -[jenkins-pipeline] is:question pipeline` and wondered about that bulk edit.